# OverlayPanel inside a Datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I need to have an overlay panel in each row of my datatable for changing a record on the fly. As you can see below:

[image]

I don't know why when I press the save button it calls two times the Setter of my attribute(str) where I store the new Age. The first time it sets the new value, but in the second set it just returns a null value.

22:32:34,502 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) 31

22:32:34,502 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)

Here's the code:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{backbean.l}" var="l" style="width: 300px;">
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{l.id}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{l.nome}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{l.age}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:graphicImage value="/img/icone.png" id="newAge">
                    <p:overlayPanel id="imgPanel" for="newAge" showEvent="mouseover"
                        hideEvent="mousedown" showCloseIcon="true">
                        <h:outputText value="Change Age:" />
                        <p:inputText value="#{backbean.str}" style="margin-left: 10px;"></p:inputText>
                        <br />
                        <p:commandButton action="#{backbean.save}" value="Save"></p:commandButton>
                    </p:overlayPanel>
                </p:graphicImage>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
```

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,

Luis

@Edit:

Guess it's solved...
Just added  dynamic="true" and it seems to work fine.
Tomorrow I'll validate that solution, and then I confirm it here.

Comment: Adding `dynamic="true"` to a `<p:overlayPanel>` as can be seen in this case does not function, if a row in a `<p:dataTable>` is AJAX updated (like some other components that just stop functioning after an AJAX update is made).